# How to loop over labels start from 1 to 4 and not from 0?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

```
InitializeComponent();

            Label[] labels = new Label[4];
            for(int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
            {
                labels[i] = new Label();
                labels[i].Text = i.ToString();
                labels[i].Location = new Point(0, i * 30);
                this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
            }
```

this will display 0, 1, 2 ,3  but I want to display 1, 2 ,3 ,4 and still make the first one at the location 0,0 and the rest with gap on the y double by 30

Comment: Could this be like `labels[i].Text = (i+1).ToString();` ? This seems more like a general programming question, not specifically gamedev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new variable which is `1` more than `i`, so it should look like this:

```
InitializeComponent();

            Label[] labels = new Label[4];
            for(int i = 0; i < labels.Length; i++)
            {
                labels[i] = new Label();
                int j = i+1;
                labels[i].Text = j.ToString();
                labels[i].Location = new Point(0, i * 30);
                this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
            }
```